# QuickBlox 10 Gb traffic/storage in free tier

Tags: ios, iphone, quickblox, videochat

I am developing a **iOS video chat app** using **QuickBlox api** but I didn't getting meaning of *10 Gb traffic/storage*. I read about it from here http://quickblox.com/plans/free/

**I have three questions:**

**Q.1)** How much storage/traffic will be used, If we started a video call to a person using iPhone for 1 hour ?

**Q.2)** 10GB traffic/storage per month for each application or per account ?

**Q.3)** Can we make video confrencening app using Quickblox api ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: use this http://quickblox.com/contact/ for non technical question regarding QB !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A.1) When you are doing a p2p video call to a person, the only traffic that will be used server-side is for logging start and end time on the server (and the like). The video traffic won't affect the 10Gig.

A.2) You should be creating one account for your app - so: both.

A.3) Video Conference with more than 2 participants is not supported natively in QuickBlox, but you can bind your video signal to more than one instance, allowing you to stream your video to multiple participants at the same time.
Of course, with higher user count, the necessary bandwidth of every user increases. If you have p2p between six users, you have to push five incoming and five outgoing video signals through each participant's internet connection. (You should think of a clever way to downsize the signal on the sender side.)

Comment: Thanx Alexander.
Could you suggest or provide any sample project code by which we achive Video Conferencing? For me it is not possible to implement it  the way you decribed using QuickBlox sdk.

Answer (score 4):

**@Deepak,**

1) Not Sure its depends upon your quality & Connection for ex. 5 minute youtube should be around 10mb.... for 360-420p videos.

2) Storage 10GB is for per month based.

3) Yes they do support Check this - http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat/Video_chat

Answer (score 0):

Q.1) How much storage/traffic will be used, If we started a video call to a person using iPhone for 1 hour ?
The data passed between users is Peer to Peer so not that much.

Q.2) 10GB traffic/storage per month for each application or per account ?
The Free tier is just that - Free so it is subject to fair use. We don't cut off at 10GB but if clients want support and SLA and better services we request that clients use the Pro or upgrade to an enterprise tier to support Quickblox to provide them with better services.

Q.3) Can we make video confrencening app using Quickblox api ?
Yes of course